# Player not teleporting from object to empty object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I assigned teleportation target and the player to an object from where I want to be teleported. But it is not working at all, as in other examples players have `RigidBody` properties, on the other hand I don't have `RigidBody` in my `NavMesh`. Is this maybe an issue? I'm trying something like this:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    thePlayer.transform.position = teleportTarget.transform.position;
}
```

This is my movement code:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject cameraPrefab;

    private PlayerMovement playerMovement;

    void Awake()
    {
        GameObject camera = Instantiate(cameraPrefab);
        camera.GetComponent<PlayerCamera>().target = transform;

        playerMovement = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
        playerMovement.cam = camera.GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
    }
}
```

Any idea to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like the trigger is never actually triggered. Do both objects that are colliding have a collider and if so do they both have the “Is trigger” enabled?

Comment: Both objects have collider and Is Trigger is enabled on both of them and it's still the same...

Comment: Could you add an debug log to check whether the OnTriggerEnter is being called? And if it is I would check whether the transform position have the same position so maybe log those positions too.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but shouldn't you set one "Is trigger" to true (teleporter), and another to false (player)?

Comment: You are indeed correct `If both GameObjects have Collider.isTrigger enabled, no collision happens. The same applies when both GameObjects do not have a Rigidbody component.`  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

Comment: @Lieke could you write a solution then? Because the action is still not working.

Comment: Okay when I have isTrigger set as true on box collider of both game objects, and a Rigidbody on an object from where I wish to teleport, player automatically teleports on the final object, how to fix this?

Comment: Okay I fixed the solution I had to set Is trigger to player to false

Answer (score 0):

To teleport a GameObject to some other GameObject you can do this:

1. Create player, teleporter, and teleporterExit
2. Add components to them:
   player -Rrigidbody, Collider
   teleporter - Collider **YOU HAVE TO CHANGE ITS "Is trigger" PROPERTY TO TRUE**

teleportExit - can be empty

3. Add this class to your teleporter as a component

```
     public class TeleporterBehavior : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject TeleporterExit;
        private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
        {
            collision.gameObject.transform.position = TeleporterExit.transform.position;
        }
    }
```

4. Add some movement to your player

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Force;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(Force, 0f));
    }
}
```

5. Put the objects in the scene so that they can interact which each other
   [image]
6. Observe how the player teleports itself after touching teleporter.

Comment: Okay so I added my movement code in a question, and I'm not working with unity 2d but I work with unity 3d, how do I add Rigidbody in my scenario?